# Ruby MongoDB insert_many

Tags: ruby, mongodb, hash, bulkinsert

I am trying to load a collection into MongoDB with `insert_many`:

```
result = @my_db[:"my_database"].insert_many([@my_hash.each { |key, value| {:id=>key, :description=>value[:description]}}])
```

`my_hash` is a hash containing many hashes, each with one key-value pair.

The collection of `my_hash` loads ok, but what I actually want is the key-values on the top level of the database collection.  Right now, I have to expand the top level of the collection to see the fields (key-value pairs).

Comment: do you get more accurate results with `map` instead of `.each` ?